# Why doesn't my code detect the member in the guild even with a valid ID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For reference, memID is initialized to message.author.id

```py
    if message.content.startswith(prefix+'jail'):
       serv = client.get_guild(message.guild.id)

       mod = serv.get_member(memID)

       if 'Moderator' in mod.roles:
           await message.channel.send("Signal")`
```

I even debugged to print memID and it printed out my ID, however this function does not detect me as a member even with the valid ID, instead initializing to NoneType. Help.

Error Log:

```
File "/home/runner/NKBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 81, in on_message
    if 'Moderator' in mod.roles:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

Comment: Do you have the members intent enabled? Both in code and on your developer portal.

Comment: I realized I forgot to enable members intent, and yes my ID is an int (it's message.author.id). Now the error is no longer there but my bot does not respond with the debug 'signal' message

Comment: `mod.roles` is a list of `discord.Role` instances, and you're checking if a string (`"Moderator"`) is in that list. That will never be True, because a string will never be in that list of Roles.

Comment: Thank you, I finally figured out it why it didn't work. Too stupid of me to use a str type for a class. Now I finally got it working by using the get_role function, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the `members intent` was not enabled, so your `discord.Member` instance couldn't be found. See the docs for how to enable them: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Next, you're checking if a string (`"Moderator"`) is in `mod.roles`. This is always `False`, because `Member.roles` is a list of `discord.Role` instances, not strings. You can also find this in the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member%20roles#discord.Member.roles

You can find the role by name using a loop, or more easily using the built-in [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get) method. The docs page has plenty of examples that explain how it works.

Lastly, instead of manually parsing message content consider just using the built-in [`Commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html) framework that does all this for you.